# dbt run-operation to call macros that have non-string arguments

Tags: jinja2, dbt

Say that I want to drop the `ajs` schema as a clean up activity on our dev db, not as part of a regular `dbt` workflow

```sh
dbt run-operation drop_schema --args '{relation: ajs}'
```

perhaps I need to wrap `drop_schema` into another macro `drop_schema_str(schema_str)` where `schema_str` is the string of the schema and it is used to make a `Relation` object before invoking `drop_schema()`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

create this macro

```sql
{% macro drop_schema_str(schema) %}
  {% set relation = api.Relation.create(database=target.database, schema=schema) %}
  {% do drop_schema(relation) %}
{% endmacro %}
```

then invoke it with

```sh
dbt run-operation drop_schema_str --args '{schema: ajs}'
```

Comment: For more complex parameters can be sent in this way:
`--args '{param1: val1, param2: val2, paramArray: ["elem1", "elem2"]}'